# Total records is different between query by sequelize and mysql when i use Op.in with offset and limits?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, limit, offset, record

How can i change my data when i query by sequelize same with mysql?

mysql query:

```
SELECT `ProjectProposal`.`id`, 
       `ProjectProposal`.`vietnamese_name`                    AS `vietnameseName`, 
       `ProjectProposal`.`english_name`                       AS `englishName`, 
       `ProjectProposal`.`implementation_months`              AS `implementationMonths`, 
       `ProjectProposal`.`total_expenditure`                  AS `totalExpenditure`, 
       `ProjectProposal`.`created_at`                         AS `createdAt`, 
       `status`.`id`                                          AS `status.id`, 
       `status`.`name`                                        AS `status.name`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`project_proposals_id` AS `projectProposalResearchFields.projectProposalId`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`research_fields_id`   AS `projectProposalResearchFields.researchFieldId`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`priority`             AS `projectProposalResearchFields.priority`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`research_line`        AS `projectProposalResearchFields.researchLine`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`deleted_at`           AS `projectProposalResearchFields.deletedAt`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`created_at`           AS `projectProposalResearchFields.createdAt`, 
       `projectProposalResearchFields`.`updated_at`           AS `projectProposalResearchFields.updatedAt`, 
       `researchType`.`id`                                    AS `researchType.id`, 
       `researchType`.`name`                                  AS `researchType.name`, 
       `researchType`.`code`                                  AS `researchType.code` 
FROM   `project_proposals` AS `ProjectProposal` 
       INNER JOIN `project_proposals_status` AS `status` 
               ON `ProjectProposal`.`project_proposals_status_id` = 
                  `status`.`id` 
                  AND `status`.`name` = 'revise' 
       INNER JOIN `project_proposals_research_fields` AS            `projectProposalResearchFields` 
               ON `ProjectProposal`.`id` = 
                  `projectProposalResearchFields`.`project_proposals_id` 
                  AND ( `projectProposalResearchFields`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
                        AND `projectProposalResearchFields`.`research_fields_id` 
                            IN ( 
                                '30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f', 
                                'cd9b0b91-86fb-4f30-bd7e-68bbe5758e9f', 
                                '897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103', 
                                '275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017' ) ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `research_types` AS `researchType` 
                    ON `ProjectProposal`.`research_types_id` = 
                       `researchType`.`id` 
LIMIT  0, 10;
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmd44.png)
**total records is 4**

sequelize query

```
    const projectProposalList = await this.projectProposalRepository.findAll({
      attributes: [
        'id',
        'vietnameseName',
        'englishName',
        'implementationMonths',
        'totalExpenditure',
        'createdAt',
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: ProjectProposalStatus,
        },
        {
          model: ProjectProposalResearchField,
          include: [ResearchField],
        },
        {
          model: ResearchType,
        },
      ],
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          {
            '$status.name$': ProjectProposalStatusEnum.REVISE,
            '$projectProposalResearchFields.researchField.id$': {
              [Op.in]: [researchFieldIds],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      offset: Number(first),
      limit: projectProposalsPerPage,
      subQuery: false,
      order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']],
    });
result:     {
      "id": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
      "vietnameseName": "Cấu trúc nano của vật liệu đa chiều cho các ứng dụng cảm biến quang điện hóa (PEC)",
      "englishName": "Multidimensional nanostructures-based for photoelectrochemical sensing applications",
      "implementationMonths": 12,
      "totalExpenditure": 20000000000,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-14T16:45:25.000Z",
      "status": {
        "id": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
        "name": "revise"
      },
      "projectProposalResearchFields": [
        {
          "projectProposalId": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
          "researchFieldId": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
          "priority": 1,
          "researchLine": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
            "name": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
            "code": "humanity"
          }
        },
        {
          "projectProposalId": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
          "researchFieldId": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
          "priority": 2,
          "researchLine": "Khoa học Xã hội",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
            "name": "Khoa học Xã hội",
            "code": "science"
          }
        },
        {
          "projectProposalId": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
          "researchFieldId": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
          "priority": 3,
          "researchLine": "Kinh tế, Luật",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
            "name": "Kinh tế, Luật",
            "code": "economic&law"
          }
        }
      ],
      "researchType": {
        "id": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
        "name": "Nghiên cứu ứng dụng",
        "code": "applied"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2483b145-6732-4e3f-a8dd-4198391b2cf9",
      "vietnameseName": "Nhận dạng và điều khiển thích nghi các hệ phi tuyến đa biến ứng dụng các thuật toán lai thông minh điều khiển tối ưu nâng cao.",
      "englishName": "Identification and control of nonlinear multivariable systems using advanced hybrid optimal control intelligence algorithms",
      "implementationMonths": 12,
      "totalExpenditure": 20000000000,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-14T16:45:25.000Z",
      "status": {
        "id": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
        "name": "revise"
      },
      "projectProposalResearchFields": [
        {
          "projectProposalId": "2483b145-6732-4e3f-a8dd-4198391b2cf9",
          "researchFieldId": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
          "priority": 1,
          "researchLine": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
            "name": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
            "code": "humanity"
          }
        }
      ],
      "researchType": {
        "id": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
        "name": "Nghiên cứu ứng dụng",
        "code": "applied"
      }
    }
    {
      "id": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
      "vietnameseName": "Cấu trúc nano của vật liệu đa chiều cho các ứng dụng cảm biến quang điện hóa (PEC)",
      "englishName": "Multidimensional nanostructures-based for photoelectrochemical sensing applications",
      "implementationMonths": 12,
      "totalExpenditure": 20000000000,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-14T16:45:25.000Z",
      "status": {
        "id": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
        "name": "revise"
      },
      "projectProposalResearchFields": [
        {
          "projectProposalId": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
          "researchFieldId": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
          "priority": 1,
          "researchLine": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
            "name": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
            "code": "humanity"
          }
        },
        {
          "projectProposalId": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
          "researchFieldId": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
          "priority": 2,
          "researchLine": "Khoa học Xã hội",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
            "name": "Khoa học Xã hội",
            "code": "science"
          }
        },
        {
          "projectProposalId": "0aaa1ab5-8692-4bee-ad2b-3baeb1767d4e",
          "researchFieldId": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
          "priority": 3,
          "researchLine": "Kinh tế, Luật",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
            "name": "Kinh tế, Luật",
            "code": "economic&law"
          }
        }
      ],
      "researchType": {
        "id": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
        "name": "Nghiên cứu ứng dụng",
        "code": "applied"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2483b145-6732-4e3f-a8dd-4198391b2cf9",
      "vietnameseName": "Nhận dạng và điều khiển thích nghi các hệ phi tuyến đa biến ứng dụng các thuật toán lai thông minh điều khiển tối ưu nâng cao.",
      "englishName": "Identification and control of nonlinear multivariable systems using advanced hybrid optimal control intelligence algorithms",
      "implementationMonths": 12,
      "totalExpenditure": 20000000000,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-14T16:45:25.000Z",
      "status": {
        "id": "897192e0-7910-4d98-a88f-f0f0128f9103",
        "name": "revise"
      },
      "projectProposalResearchFields": [
        {
          "projectProposalId": "2483b145-6732-4e3f-a8dd-4198391b2cf9",
          "researchFieldId": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
          "priority": 1,
          "researchLine": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null,
          "researchField": {
            "id": "275ffd79-239f-4b8b-a9ad-92ed50e95017",
            "name": "Khoa học Nhân văn",
            "code": "humanity"
          }
        }
      ],
      "researchType": {
        "id": "30ce149a-6db3-4e04-8e8e-7111761d874f",
        "name": "Nghiên cứu ứng dụng",
        "code": "applied"
      }
    }
```

**total records is 2**

I hope you guys can help me, thank you so much

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` will give you an unordered/random set of rows.

Comment: Try to add the option `raw: true` and count a number of objects again